# Lifecycle of logs in spark application

Tags: apache-spark

What is the life cycle of logs when running spark application.

From what I have understood Spark driver takes care of running the application and actual work is done by spark executor nodes.

Hence whatever I log from application, would be going to spark executor log directory. But once application fails, I would be interested in known why it had failed, since the failure reason would be present in executor logs, does spark take care of aggregating all the executor logs?

Does it matter if spark running in yarn or standalone mode?